# Что это за скрипт? Что он делает?

Tags: javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    (function(jq) {

        jq.autoScroll = function(ops) {

        ops = ops || {};

        ops.styleClass = ops.styleClass || 'scroll-to-top-button';

        var t = jq('<div class="'+ops.styleClass+'"></div>'),

        d = jq(ops.target || document);

        jq(ops.container || 'body').append(t);

        t.css({

            opacity: 0,

            position: 'absolute',

            top: 0,

            rigth: 0

                    }).click(function() {

            jq('html,body').animate({

                scrollTop: 0

            }, ops.scrollDuration || 1000);

        });

        d.scroll(function() {

            var sv = d.scrollTop();

            if (sv < 10) {

                t.clearQueue().fadeOut(ops.hideDuration || 200);

                return;

            }

            t.css('display', '').clearQueue().animate({

                top: sv,

                opacity: 0.8

            }, ops.showDuration || 500);

        });

    };

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){

    $.autoScroll({

        scrollDuration: 2000,

        showDuration: 600,

        hideDuration: 300

    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скрипт очень напоминает деятельность кнопки "На верх", применяемой на больших страницах для плавной автопрокрутки до самого верха. Эта кнопка появляется после того как прокрутишь вниз немного, и пропадает соответственно если автоматически доехало до самого верха.